# Type testing with templates C++

Tags: c++, templates

So I have a function that takes two possible argument types, each of which is a lambda function type I have predefined. The two possibilities are CellFType and FType. The function is nearly identical for both cases, but at one line I need it to do two different things depending on the FunctionType. I want to avoid having a whole extra overload for this so I have templated it as such

```
/// Returns the integral 2 norm of a function

template <typename FunctionType>
double norm(const FunctionType &f)
{
    double value = 0.0;

    for (size_t iT = 0; iT < n_cells; iT++)
    {
        QuadratureRule quadT = cell_quads[iT];
        for (size_t iqn = 0; iqn < quadT.size(); iqn++)
        {
            double qr_weight = quadT[iqn].w;

            VectorRd f_on_qr = (typeid(FunctionType) == typeid(FType<VectorRd>) ? 
            f(quadT[iqn].vector()) : f(quadT[iqn].vector(), cells[iT])); // *ERROR*

            value += qr_weight * scalar_product(f_on_qr, f_on_qr);
        }
    }

    return sqrt(value);
}
```

FType and CellFType are also both templated as such:

```
template <typename T>
using CellFType = std::function<T(const VectorRd &, const Cell *)>;

template <typename T>
using FType = std::function<T(const VectorRd &)>;
```

Why is this causing issues? How can I type test properly here?

Comment: How exactly are you getting the types of your lambdas?

Comment: I'll put some more detailed code in

Comment: @StephenNewell is that helpful, or just confuses things more?

Comment: I asked because if you're using actual lambdas, I wasn't sure how you'd get the types at compile-time.  The code you've added does not, in fact, get the types of lambads, since a lambda isn't the same as an std::function.

Comment: haven't used typeid much myself, looks like you need to call std::type_index(tid)?  I'd use std::is_same though :

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same

Comment: The example code helps.  What version of C++ are you using?

Comment: It doesn't matter that at run-time, only one branch of the conditional operator will be evaluated. At compile time, during template instantiation, both branches must be well-formed. With sufficiently modern compiler, you could use `if constexpr`. Alternatively, break just the one problematic line out into a separate helper function, and provide two overloads of that.

Comment: @StephenNewell C++ 17 I think, but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I might just do the two helper functions. Soundslike the easiest fix

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the comments, to call an overloaded function, is of course the most straightforward to understand and therefore best approach.

But, sometimes it's nice to keep it all inlined. Since you're using C++17, there's this helper class that gets used a lot with `std::visit`:

```cpp
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;
```

It takes a bunch of lambdas, and converts them into a class with a call operator overload to invoke each lambda. You can use this to dispatch your case as well:

```cpp
VectorRd f_on_qr = overloaded {
    [&](FType<VectorRd> g) { return g(quadT[iqn].vector()); },
    [&](CellFType<VectorRd> g) { return g(quadT[iqn].vector(), cells[iT])); }
} (f);
```

Proof of concept:
https://godbolt.org/z/G5qWGK